# Menu creation in Eclipse(Android Developement)

Tags: android, eclipse, menu, logcat

I am new to Android development and I am sorry if this is a repeat but I tried looking at other solutions and they didn't help. So here's my problem:

I tried creating a simple menu that doesn't do anything. It should just pop open when the menu button is pressed. It worked on one emulator(Target Android 3.0(API level 11)) but throws open the logcat in others(Android 1.5 and 4.0) on which I tried and gives the message: "The application menu (process menu.intro) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again".

My MainActivity.java file:

```
 package menu.intro;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

My mainmenu.xml file in /res/menu folder:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/buttonone"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
      android:title="@string/showimage1"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/buttontwo"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
      android:title="@string/showimage2" />

    <item android:id="@+id/buttonthree"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon3"
      android:title="@string/showimage3" />
    </menu>
```

My activity_main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The logcat is something like this which is all greek to me:

```
02-16 17:46:19.171: I/jdwp(747): received file descriptor 10 from ADB
02-16 17:46:19.211: W/System.err(747): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler    defined
02-16 17:46:19.211: W/System.err(747): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
02-16 17:46:19.591: W/ResourceType(747): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020004 (t=1 e=4) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
02-16 17:46:19.601: D/AndroidRuntime(747): Shutting down VM
02-16 17:46:19.601: W/dalvikvm(747): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
02-16 17:46:19.601: E/AndroidRuntime(747): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{menu.intro/menu.intro.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1626)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at menu.intro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  ... 11 more
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:103)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  ... 22 more
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/title_bar_shadow.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020004
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1641)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:113)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  ... 26 more
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/title_bar_shadow.9.png
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:392)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1634)
02-16 17:46:19.631: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  ... 28 more
02-16 17:46:19.671: I/dalvikvm(747): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-16 17:46:19.681: I/dalvikvm(747): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-16 17:46:26.052: I/Process(747): Sending signal. PID: 747 SIG: 9
```

A big thanks for patiently reading my question! Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you need to change

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

to

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Its still showing the message and throwing up a bunch of colorful lines in the logcat.